# Простая сортировка DIV по номеру, и алфавиту

Tags: javascript

```js
var sortByNameBtn = document.getElementById('sortByName');
var sortByPriceBtn = document.getElementById('sortByPrice');

function sortingByName(){
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  
}

function sortingByPrice(){
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

}

sortByNameBtn.addEventListener('click', sortingByName);
sortByPriceBtn.addEventListener('click', sortingByPrice);
```

```css
.item {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">12321</div>
    <div class="item-name">Car</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">123</div>
    <div class="item-name">Table</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">88</div>
    <div class="item-name">Toys</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">1223</div>
    <div class="item-name">Window</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">19</div>
    <div class="item-name">Bad</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">50</div>
    <div class="item-name">Mouse</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">500</div>
    <div class="item-name">iPhone</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">100</div>
    <div class="item-name">Mobile</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">12</div>
    <div class="item-name">Cake</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">500</div>
    <div class="item-name">Laptop</div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>
  <button id="sortByName">Sort by name</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button id="sortByPrice">
  Sort By price
</button>
</p>
```

Как можно на чистом JS отсортировать div'ы, по номеру, и имени? Ранее сортировал только списки, тут загвоздка в том что бы получить доступ именно к имени или номеру.

Comment: Можно машину за 12321 руб XD

Comment: располагайте весь код **всегда** в вопросе, а не на сторонних ресурсах. здесь есть сниппет, который спокойно воспроизводит html+js+css

Comment: по поводу вопроса - имеет смысл данные, пожалуй, хранить в виде объекта, к которому легко применить тип сортировки и потом перерисовать DOM. А сейчас приходится заниматься лишней работой, по сбору данных по селекторам, располагать, опять же, их как объект ключ-значение и только потом делать сортировку и перерисовку

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, исправил

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решил, с применением display flex на родителя.

```js
var sortByNameBtn = document.getElementById('sortByName');
var sortByPriceBtn = document.getElementById('sortByPrice');

function sortingByName() {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

  // get all items as an array and call the sort method
  Array.from(items).sort(function(a, b) {
    // get the text content
    a = a.querySelector('.item-name').innerText.toLowerCase()
    b = b.querySelector('.item-name').innerText.toLowerCase()
    return (a > b) - (a < b)
  }).forEach(function(n, i) {
    n.style.order = i
  })

}

function sortingByPrice(){
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
  
  Array.from(items).sort(function(a, b) {
    // using ~~ to cast the value to a number instead of a string
    a = ~~a.querySelector('.item-price').innerText
    b = ~~b.querySelector('.item-price').innerText
    return a - b
  }).forEach(function(n, i) {
    n.style.order = i
  })
}

sortByNameBtn.addEventListener('click', sortingByName);
sortByPriceBtn.addEventListener('click', sortingByPrice);
```

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">12321</div>
    <div class="item-name">Car</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">123</div>
    <div class="item-name">Table</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">88</div>
    <div class="item-name">Toys</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">1223</div>
    <div class="item-name">Window</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">19</div>
    <div class="item-name">Bad</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">50</div>
    <div class="item-name">Mouse</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">500</div>
    <div class="item-name">iPhone</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">100</div>
    <div class="item-name">Mobile</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">12</div>
    <div class="item-name">Cake</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-price">500</div>
    <div class="item-name">Laptop</div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>
  <button id="sortByName">Sort by name</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button id="sortByPrice">
  Sort By price
</button>
</p>
```